# etable (fixest package) won't work when knitting rmarkdown (but does when running the chunk only)

Tags: r-markdown, fixest

I'm using the etable command from the fixest package to create regression outputs in an rmarkdown report. It used to work without any issues until recently, but now (new laptop, everything reinstalled), the etable output appears when I run the codeblock, but as soon as I knit the rmarkdown, the following error message occurs:

"Quitting from lines 13-24 [unnamed-chunk-1] (test456.Rmd)
Error in `etable()`:
! Objekt 'res_df' nicht gefunden
Backtrace:

1. fixest::etable(ols_fe_models, markdown = T)"

(object res_df not found)

Reproducible example:

```
library(fixest)

data(USArrests)

ols_fe_models <- feols(Murder~Assault,
                       data = USArrests)

etable(ols_fe_models,
       markdown = T)
```

Works when running the chunk, but not when knitting.

Any help is appreciated, so I do not have to rewrite everything using another package...

Thanks!

I have tried

- loading older versions of both the etable and the rmarkdown package and R, and
- I have tried to run it on the posit cloud, to exclude that it is my r installation (https://posit.cloud/content/7303651), with no success.